# SASS for wordpress compiling, but affects are not visible

Tags: wordpress, caching, sass, localhost

I have my wordpress site running in local development. If I make changes to the html and php code I can see it on refresh. I also have Sass-watch running. If I make changes to the sass file it says:

```
Change detected to: src/scss/site/_nav.scss
      write src/style.css
      write src/style.css.map
```

However I am unable to see the changes on localhost. Can anyone tell me why it is behaving this way? and how can I see the changes when i hit refresh.

**EDIT:** I understand this may have to due with caching. How can I set the SASS caching to false. a `.scss-cache` folder gets created .

Comment: What canof changes are you performing?? can you add the code snippet you want to test ?? class and html adding the stylesheet

Comment: This won't be related to the `.sass-cache` it just sounds like good old browser caching of the stylesheet. if you have dev tools open you can choose to disable caching and it will load the new version of `style.css` each time you refresh.

Alternatively, when you enqueue the stylesheet into wp_head() you can opt to add a cache buster string there, this could just be a randomly generated string, just remember to remove it when you are finished.

Comment: No you are right, it sounds like good ol browser caching. I was able to get it to work with crtl + f5.